# Introspection: how do we get the name of a class within a class?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku

Say we have

```
class Foo {}
```

Is there a way to obtain "Foo" from within the class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

```
class Foo {
    say ::?CLASS.^name; # OUTPUT: Foo
}
```

Comment: Also: `module Foo { say $?MODULE.^name }` for module names, and `role Foo { say $?ROLE.^name }; Foo.new` for roles.  Note that you actually need to instantiate the role to get the role body executed.

Answer (score 7):

Kaiepi's solution has its place, which I'll get to below, but also consider:

```
class Foo {
    say Foo.perl;         # Foo
    say OUR.WHO;          # Foo
    ::?PACKAGE
}
```

## `Foo.perl`

This provides a simple answer to your literal question (though it ignores what you're really after, as explained in your comment below and as suggested by the `metaprogramming` tag and your use of the word "introspection").

## `OUR.WHO`

I think this is typically more appropriate than `::?CLASS.^name` for several reasons:

- Looks less line-noisy.
- Works for *all* forms of package, i.e. ones declared with the built in declarators `package`, `module`, `grammar`, or `role` as well as `class`, and also custom declarators like [`actor`](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-actors), `monitor`, etc.
- Will lead readers to mostly directly pertinent issues if they investigate [`OUR`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#index-entry-OUR_(package)) and/or [`.WHO`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#WHO) in contrast to mostly distracting arcana if they investigate [the `::?...` construct](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Looking_up_names).

## `::?CLASS` vs `::?PACKAGE`

`OUR.WHO` only works in a *value* grammatical slot, not a *type* grammatical slot. For the latter you need a suitable `::?...` form, eg:

```
class Foo { has ::?CLASS $bar }
```

And these `::?...` forms also work as values:

```
class Foo { has $bar = ::?CLASS }
```

So, despite their relative ugliness, they're more general in this particular sense. That said, if generality is at a premium then `::?PACKAGE` goes one better because it works for all forms of package.

Comment: I actually don't know the name of the class, because it's part of an automatically generated string that's going to be EVAL'ed

Comment: Answer edited. I only came up with `OUR.WHO` because your question and my dislike of `::?CLASS` drove me to it. I'm curious what you think of it. I also kinda like `OUR.^name`.